# How to make Kronecker product of two random vectors of vectors?

Tags: c++

I need to make a function which takes two parameters (two vectors of vectors) and as a result returns a vector of vectors which is a Kronecker product of two given vectors of vectors.

Whatever I do, my new vector of vectors is created by the same number (the one which should be only on the last position). For example if I have vector of vectors A: {3, -1},{0, 5} and B:{4,3,15},{0, -5, 2} my Kronecker product will be: {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10}, {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10} etc, instead of {12, 9, 45, -4, -3, -15}, {0, -15, 6, 0, 5, -2}, {0, 0, 0, 20, 15, 75}, {0, 0, 0, 0, -25, 10}

```
Matrix KroneckersProduct(Matrix A, Matrix B){
    Matrix mat=CreateMatrix(NoRows(A)*NoRows(B),NoCols(A)*NoCols(B));
    for(int i=0;i<NoRows(A)*NoRows(B);i++){
        for(int j=0;j<NoCols(A)*NoCols(B);j++){
            for(int k=0;k<NoRows(A);k++){
                for(int l=0;l<NoRows(B);l++){
                    for(int m=0;m<NoCols(A);m++){
                        for(int n=0;n<NoCols(B);n++){
                            mat.at(i).at(j)=A.at(k).at(m)*B.at(l).at(n);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return mat;
}
```

Comment: Please show us your code ([edit] your question); then we'll be able to help you find bugs in it. We're not going to write the whole thing for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the algorithm for Kronecker product. Maybe I switched `v1` and `v2`

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using Matrix = std::vector<std::vector<double>>;

Matrix KroneckersProduct(Matrix v1, Matrix v2){
    Matrix v(v1.size() * v2.size(), std::vector<double>(v1[0].size() * v2[0].size()));
    for (std::size_t z1(0); z1 < v1.size(); ++z1) {
        for (std::size_t z2(0); z2 < v2.size(); ++z2) {
            for (std::size_t z3(0); z3 < v1[0].size(); ++z3) {
                for (std::size_t z4(0); z4 < v2[0].size(); ++z4) {
                    v[z1*v2.size() + z2][z3*v2[0].size() + z4] = v1[z1][z3] * v2[z2][z4];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return v;
}

int main() {
    Matrix v1{{3, -1},{0, 5}};
    Matrix v2{{4,3,15}, {0, -5, 2}};

    Matrix v(KroneckersProduct(v1, v2));

    for (const auto& row : v) {
        for (const auto& cell : row) {
            std::cout << cell << " ";
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
12 9 45 -4 -3 -15 
0 -15 6 -0 5 -2 
0 0 0 20 15 75 
0 -0 0 0 -25 10
```